# Create groups on base of the non-zero filled columns combination

Tags: r

i am having a hard time to solve this problem. Im going to explain it the best on base of the example, lets have a look at the data below:

```
    order type_a type_b type_c type_d
1     1      0     50     10      0
2     2     10      0      0     80
3     3     15      0      0     35
4     4      0      0     30      0
5     5      0     20     40      0
```

and `dput`:

```
data <- structure(list(order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), type_a = c(0, 10, 15, 
0, 0), type_b = c(50, 0, 0, 0, 20), type_c = c(10, 0, 0, 30, 
40), type_d = c(0, 80, 35, 0, 0)), .Names = c("order", "type_a", 
"type_b", "type_c", "type_d"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

We can see that the first column tells us the order number, the rest of the columns tell us what *belongs* to this order. Additionally if the type_* column is filled with 0, then it is not relevant.

I would like to create a new column that defines groups based on "order description" --> type_* columns. For example for order 1 & order 5, we have same type_* columns filled with no 0 values, therefore they belong to the same group, same is for order 2 & 3, etc.

My final result should look like this:

```
   order type_a type_b type_c type_d   group
1     1      0     50     10      0 group_1
2     2     10      0      0     80 group_2
3     3     15     10      0     35 group_2
4     4      0      0     30      0 group_3
5     5      0     20     40      0 group_1
```

Just for your information, in my real data i do have more then 4 columns type_* --> there is about 10-15 of them!

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your groups are defined by the presence or absence of 0 in columns 2 to 5. Test for 0, collapse the TRUE/FALSE values as a string and you get a unique string for each group. Convert to a factor:

```
> data$group = factor(apply(data[,2:5] ==0,1,paste,collapse=""))
> data
  order type_a type_b type_c type_d              group
1     1      0     50     10      0 TRUEFALSEFALSETRUE
2     2     10      0      0     80 FALSETRUETRUEFALSE
3     3     15      0      0     35 FALSETRUETRUEFALSE
4     4      0      0     30      0  TRUETRUEFALSETRUE
5     5      0     20     40      0 TRUEFALSEFALSETRUE
```

Now the names are ugly, so change the levels:

```
> class(data$group)
[1] "factor"
> levels(data$group)=paste("group_",1:length(levels(data$group)))
> data
  order type_a type_b type_c type_d    group
1     1      0     50     10      0 group_ 2
2     2     10      0      0     80 group_ 1
3     3     15      0      0     35 group_ 1
4     4      0      0     30      0 group_ 3
5     5      0     20     40      0 group_ 2
```

If all those capital TRUEFALSE hurts your eyes, a simple fix will make a neat binary number:

```
> data$group = factor(apply(0+(data[,2:5] ==0),1,paste,collapse=""))
> data
  order type_a type_b type_c type_d group
1     1      0     50     10      0  1001
2     2     10      0      0     80  0110
3     3     15      0      0     35  0110
4     4      0      0     30      0  1101
5     5      0     20     40      0  1001
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar, to avoid the `apply` call you could do `do.call(paste, c(data.frame(data[2:5] != 0), sep="-"))`

Comment: Just did some benchmarking - that's a lot faster. Nice.

Comment: @RonakShah with [2:5] you selected rows 2:5.. you probably meant [,2:5], to select the columns 2:5.

Comment: @Wimpel nope, [2:5] doesn't select rows, [2:5, ] does.

Answer (score 2):

data.table solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, id := .GRP, by = list( do.call(paste0, c( data.frame( data[,2:5] != 0 ) ) ) ) ][, id := paste0( "Group_", id)][]

#    order type_a type_b type_c type_d      id
# 1:     1      0     50     10      0 Group_1
# 2:     2     10      0      0     80 Group_2
# 3:     3     15      0      0     35 Group_2
# 4:     4      0      0     30      0 Group_3
# 5:     5      0     20     40      0 Group_1
```

Answer (score 1):

This could fail in some situtations, but, this is a fun answer because we can use R for what it's actually built for. Statistical programming.

```
set.seed(42)
cols <- grep("type_", names(d))
d$group <- kmeans(d[cols], 4)$cluster
# d$group <- paste0("group_", d$group)
```

The nature of k-means clustering is such that "always" 0 columns tend to have a strong categorizing effect on the results.

Notes:

1) We use `grep` to identify columns, because using numeric references to column names leads to problems in the future if your data is not in the same shape, or changes positions. It's also more readable for someone else reviewing your code.

2) We should avoid using the variable name `data` because it is a function in base R.

Comment: The number of clusters (groups) is potentially 2^number of columns, since its a binary number. If you don't know in advance how many groups there are, then computing how many in order to put in the `kmeans` arg is probably as complex as doing the actual calculation...

Comment: Yes, the analyst would have to do some traditional work like an elbow plot. I said "fun", I didn't say anything about practical.

Comment: R stopped being about the practical and all about the fun (hey, hex stickers!) a few years ago, I noticed /snark

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand your comment and didn't intend for my previous one to come across rude if that's what you meant with "/snark"

Comment: No, its okay, its just there's a trend with R to bang on and on about stuff being "fun" when the "fun" code presented is 25 times slower than a less "fun" solution that requires understanding R a bit better. "snark" is just me being a grumpy old man about this!

Comment: Understood, what was the hex stickers reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181372/discussion-between-spacedman-and-brandon-bertelsen).